# Dynamic Array in table HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vG6tY/2/)

I have an Array which i need to convert it into Table format to be displayed in HTML.

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat='(key, value) in data[0]'>{{key}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">
            <td ng-repeat="item in data[key]" ng-if="$index!=0">{{item}}</td>

        </tr>
    </table>

var data = [{
    "recordno": "001",
        "firstname": "Brock",
        "middlename": "Edward",
        "lastname": "Lesnar",
        "gender": "male",
        "dateofbirth": "1980-01-01T20:20:19.198Z",
        "dateofdeath": null,
        "status": "archive"
}, {
    "recordno": "002",
        "firstname": "John",
        "middlename": "E",
        "lastname": "Cena",
        "gender": "male",
        "dateofbirth": "1980-01-01T20:20:19.198Z",
        "dateofdeath": null,
        "status": "archive"
}];

function TableController($scope) {
    $scope.data = data;
}
```

I am facing with 2 issues :-

1. Array in table automatically gets sorted. I want to display records as they are in Array.
2. I want to show `Status` values to be shown as `button` & when clicked on btn it calls `ng-click`.

What is the right way to do this?

Is there any other way to do this. Because Array is Dynamically passed.

Comment: What is the array sorted by? It looks already sorted in the example you gave, could you improve the example?

Comment: It is sorted alphabetically...i don't want it to be sorted...i want my columns to be like this :- record no, firstname, middlename, lastname, etc...as they are in Array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since different browsers have different conventions about sorting keys of (non-Array) objects, I suggest you have an additional array of column-names to be sure your values will always be rendered as expected (in all browsers).

Then you can use a filter to convert any item (in data) to an array based on the order specified in the `columns` array.

The implementation might look like this:

```
var columns = [...];
var data = [...];

.controller('TableController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.columns = columns;
    $scope.data = data;
})

.filter('sortByColumn', function () {
    return function (obj, columns) {
        var item = [];
        angular.forEach(columns, function (col) {
            item.push(obj[col]);
        });
        return item;
    };
});
```

Then, you can modify your HTML like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><th ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col}}</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td ng-repeat="val in item | sortByColumn:columns">{{val}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wmh3B/)**.

---

**UPDATE:**

Or, see this **[other short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wmh3B/3/)** featuring a button.

Comment: This is working nicely...How to solve my 2nd issue...i want to show `status` as button & call `ng-click` & call a method which passes `id` as argument.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not quite clear (to me) what exaclty you want. Take a look at my updated answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I want Archive as a Button...in ur result!

Comment: Please take a look at the answer (I updated the last fiddle).

Answer (score 1):

I am using a function like below

```
function RepeatData(TemplateString, JSONValue, JOSNFields, Parent, Options) {
        var settings = $.extend({ "OnItemBound": null, "Delimiter": "" }, Options);
        for (var i = 0; i < JSONValue.length; i++) {
            var rowValue = TemplateString;
            for (var j = 0; j < JOSNFields.length; j++) {
                rowValue = rowValue.replace(new RegExp(settings.Delimiter + JOSNFields[j] + settings.Delimiter, 'g'), JSONValue[i][JOSNFields[j]]);
            }
            var rowElement = $(rowValue);
            if (settings.OnItemBound)
                settings.OnItemBound(rowElement, JSONValue[i]);
            Parent.append(rowElement);
        }
}
```

and you need to call this function like this
Suppose my data is

```
var dataExample = [{
    "recordno": "001",
        "firstname": "Brock",
        "middlename": "Edward",
}, {
    "recordno": "002",
        "firstname": "John",
        "middlename": "E",
}];
```

then

```
RepeatData("<tr><td>#firstname#</td><td>#middlename#</td></tr>",dataExample,['firstname','middlename'],$("#divTableContainer").find("tbody"),{ "OnItemBound": function (rowElement, rowData) { AddSelectionProperty(rowElement, rowData) }, "Delimiter": "#" });
```

Not sure that this will meet your needs, but this would help you

Comment: Thanks for answer...can u put this in fiddle pls...as i was trying it in fiddle but doesn't shown any results..!

Comment: @Anup sorry this is not working in jsfiddle,But im using this in my current project in VisualStudio 2010 with Jquery 1.10.1. I dont have knowledge in angular js